# Issues using and manipulating [h]:mm:ss custom excel format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a small problem that probally has a very simple fix that I can not seem to find/ do.

I have some data in [h]:mm:ss format, lets say "23:34:54" in a cell on a spreadsheet. I would then like to subtract from that a dynamic value, lets say "5:00:00"

I've tried to find a way to code this, currently my code is as follows

```
TimeCheck = Cells(NewLastRowNumber + 4, 2) - Cells(NewLastRowNumber, 2)
TimeCheck = Application.Text(TimeCheck, "[h]:mm:ss")

hTime = Application.Text("5:00:00", "[h]:mm:ss")

TimeTest= hTime - TimeCheck
```

However when I run the code I always get a  Type MisMatch Error on the `TestTime` line. I belive this is down to how the I managed to get the data in the correct format. The value of time check is always correct

I also tried to `TimeCheck = Format(TimeCheck, "[h]:mm:ss")` but I was never able to get that to work.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appricated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateAdd to subtract 5 hours from a given time like below, this will take the data from cell A1, convert it to date/time and then subtract 300 minutes, then write the value into B2:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Range("B2") = DateAdd("n", -300, CDate(ws.Range("A1")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Run-time error '13': Type mismatch` indicates that you are trying to perform an arithmetic operation between two strings.

In your code:

•   This line generates `TimeCheck` as datatype double

```
    TimeCheck = Cells(NewLastRowNumber + 4, 2) - Cells(NewLastRowNumber, 2)
```

•   This line makes `TimeCheck` as datatype string

```
    TimeCheck = Application.Text(TimeCheck, "[h]:mm:ss")
```

•   This line generates `hTime` as datatype string

```
    hTime = Application.Text("5:00:00", "[h]:mm:ss")
```

•   This line tries to apply an Arithmetic operator between two ‘Strings’

```
    TimeTest= hTime - TimeCheck
```

First perform the Arithmetic operation then convert the result to string
Try this:

```
    TimeCheck = Cells(NewLastRowNumber + 4, 2) - Cells(NewLastRowNumber, 2)
    hTime = CDbl(TimeSerial(5, 0, 0))
    TimeTest = hTime - TimeCheck
    TimeTest = Application.Text(TimeTest, "[h]:mm:ss")
```